# Bash scripting and gdal - how to refer to elements in an array variable?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, loops, gdal

I am trying to use gdal in a bash script. I have several input raster files, in ENVI format, in different directories, and want to give new outputnames, in GTiff format.

The idea is then to run the code in a loop, so this is just an initial test, but does not want to work as expected.

This is my abstracted code

```
#!/bin/bash

#Inputfiles a:
echo ${a[*]}
#/home/dir1/dir2/filename1 /home/dir1/dir4/filename2 /home/dir1/dir5/filename3

#outputnames b:
echo ${b[*]}
#outputname1 outputname2 outputname3


#this works, just to test
echo ${a[1]} ${b[1]} > file1.txt

#this works
gdal_translate –of GTiff /home/dir1/dir2/filename1 outputname1

#but this does not want to work? why?
gdal_translate –of GTiff ${a[1]} ${b[1]}

#error: Too many command options
```

Some initial code for a loop below, but the 1-element test above does not work yet.

```
for i in ${a[*]}
do
   gdal_translate –of GTiff ${a[i]} ${b[i]}
done
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does `echo "::${a[1]}::${b[1]}::"` print?

Comment: It prints: `::/home/bspies/hostshare/A_Data_PhD/A_Alldata/B_Cameroon2/cameroon2_output/Cameroon2_Dry_ASAR_20100424_SLC_0_VVVH_VH_2x4_15m/Cameroon2_Dry_ASAR_20100424_SLC_0_VVVH.cmli.utm_15m_VH::Cameroon2_Dry_ASAR_20100424_SLC_0_VVVH_VH_2x4_15m::`  This is the first elements of both arrays, which I shortened in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to close this question, this is what I did. I found a work-around for this situation:

1. All my files were in separate folders, so I had to move them into a common folder. This was key to looping though the files.
2. Then to convert all the ENVI files to `.tif` files I could use

:

```
for filename in *.img;
do
    gdal_translate -of GTiff -a_nodata 0 $filename ../d_Separate_tif/$filename.tif
done
```

I'll close this question now.

Answer (score 1):

For your loop, you want to iterate over each index of the array.  The code `for i in ${a[*]}` iterates over each *element* of the `a` array.  Here's what you actually want:

```
for i in ${!a[@]}; do
    gdal_translate –of GTiff "${a[$i]}" "${b[$i]}"
done
```

This assumes that the indexing is the same in each array.  Note that I wrapped `${a[$i]}` and `${b[$i]}` in quotes so that elements with spaces are given to the command as one argument.  I assume this is why the single command `gdal_translate –of GTiff ${a[1]} ${b[1]}` gives the error "too many command options".

Comment: Thanks @Christopher-Neylan for the `@` vs `*` pointer. It however still gives the same error of `too many command options.` even with one line of `gdal_translate –of GTiff "${a[1]}" "${b[1]}"` Maybe it's to do with the format of my input arrays? I'll play around a bit, but any suggestions are still welcome!